# mat-autocomplete to be used with a button (like md-autocomplete)

Tags: angular, angular-material2, mat-autocomplete

In Angular Material 1, it was possible to open the `md-autocomplete` dropdown with a button click (cf [doc](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete#custom-template)).

In Angular Material 2, I don't see this possibility with `mat-autocomplete` (cf [doc](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview)). Is this still possible in some way ? How ? I was thinking about having the `input` hidden and trigger `openPanel` but it seems a bit overkill for such a simple usage...

Thanks for your help

**[edit]**
For now my code is like this (I did not add the button since I'm not sure that's right way)

```
<mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Pronostique le futur vainqueur" aria-label="Vainqueur" matInput
             [(ngModel)]="worldcupWinner" name="worldcupWinner" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let team of teams" [value]="team">
          <img class="flag" [src]="team.flag_url" />
          <span class="label">{{ team.name }}</span>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you add your code, I'll add the reference and function call to it.

**edit**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input #trigger="matAutocompleteTrigger" type="text" placeholder="Pronostique le futur vainqueur" aria-label="Vainqueur" matInput [(ngModel)]="worldcupWinner" name="worldcupWinner" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let team of teams" [value]="team">
      <img class="flag" [src]="team.flag_url" />
      <span class="label">{{ team.name }}</span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-raised-button (click)="openThatPanel()">OPEN IT</button>
```

component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('trigger') trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;

openThatPanel() {
  setTimeout(_ => this.trigger.openPanel());
}
```

I couoldn't get it to open without a setTimeout around the trigger.openPanel() unfortunately.

Comment: Your edit works. But that means I still need the `<input>` and I'd like to get rid of it (or hide it). Like when you click the button, the dropdown is displayed just below the button (for the ngModel to be filled, I guess I can just listen to the optionSelected event).

Comment: Nevermind, I thing I'm not using the right component since the "autocomplete" feature is bound to the input, and not in the dropdown...

Comment: Glad to be of help :)